# Codeigniter Ajax form submit and ajax retrieve data in table

Tags: codeigniter-2

is there any complete example in codeigniter where i can submit a form via ajax and same time get value from database to in table also via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

ajax works pretty the same way no matter what framework you are using, the logic is the same. you should first learn ajax in complete and then you can use it in any framework you can.

if you can drive a car, you can drive any car.

here is an example for ajax with codeigniter

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-codeigniter/

hope, this helps